# how do i make an exe of my node cli application

Tags: node.js

I'm pretty new to coding and I've made a small project in nodejs with a few tools which is all run on the command line. I'm really struggling to find a way to make this an exe file and allow other people to download said exe file and run the app. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

I've looked at packages such as nw.js and electron but these seem like they're for browser based applications - could just do with pointing in the right direction

Comment: You can check this tute that uses Nexe for this https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/ . But note that building an portable executable for an app made with node is not a simple operation because you'll have to package nodejs itself with your code.

Comment: look at these : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe, https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg